# Alsa chroot java program doesn't find microphone

Tags: java, alsa, 32-bit, microphone, chroot

I made a chroot environment from an architecture i386. Now I installed ALSA on it (alsa-base, alsa-utils, asound2). I mounted the proc,sys and dev directory too. 
Then I tested my microphone with the following command line:

```
arecord -d 10 test.wav
```

And i played it with

```
aplay test.wav
```

this works fine. But when I'm running an external library that uses the microphone it doesn't work at all. I got the following errors:

```
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
shm_open() failed: Function not implemented
```

Then I tried to restart alsa-utils

```
/etc/init.d/alsa-utils restart
```

Got the following error: http://pastebin.com/hkGBzagE

What could be an solution to get java alsa let them work together in a chroot environment?

Thanks in advance

Noizer

Comment: XCB is an X library, and has nothing to do with audio.

Comment: Ok but it occurs when i do some audio things. How can i fix that or how can I (re)install that library?

Comment: It's possible that whatever software you're using tries to show a window "now recording" or something like that. Anyway, to find out which files are being accessed, try `strace`.